# How to upload a pdf to google cloud storage with php?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload a pdf to google cloud storage but there's a moment I haven't been able to install all the tools that google asks for in your documentation using composer my code:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;


$app = array();
$app['bucket_name']= "name_of_bucket";

$PATH = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$Name_File = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

//call to function 
upload_object($app['bucket_name'],$PATH,$Name_File);


 //function

function upload_object($bucketName, $objectName, $source){

   $storage = new StorageClient();
   $file = fopen($source, 'r');
   $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
   $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
    'name' => $objectName
   ]);

   echo "Send to data to google cloud storage";
 }
```

I don't know what I'm failing on and I'm checking the bucket name and everything correct

Comment: What's the error ? What component failed to install ?

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that stands out is it looks like you are missing a require for the file that stores composer's autoload information. See [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) for some more details. Assuming your project structure looks like the following after running `composer install` from the root:

- project_folder

  - upload_test.php
  - composer.json
  - vendor/

Adding `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` to the top of your script should help.